# Issue processing an array created with new operator

Tags: c++, new-operator

I am fairly new to the concepts of *new*, *delete*, and *pointers*, so perhaps the solution is obvious to people reading this, but I am honestly perplexed.

I am supposed to have an array which is initialized at 2 elements, but as the user enters more numbers, it would constantly expand by 2 elements using the *new* operator until the user enters "-1".

While I have coding to allow the array to grow, the [results are disappointing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFpeh.png) when the program then processes the array to return the difference between the smallest number in the array, and each of the other numbers. The only hint I was given was: "When you change the capacity, you don’t copy from the original array to the new one.", however, I am not sure what to make of that.

A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int *ptr;   //pointer to array
int capacity = 2;   //capactity of array
int size = 0;       //how many ints recorded in array
ptr = new int[capacity];
int tmp = 0;

int *numArray = new int[capacity];

while (true){
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    if (num == -1) break;
    if (size == capacity){
        int *temp = new int[capacity + 2];
        capacity += 2;
        delete[]ptr;
        ptr = temp;
    }
    ptr[size++] = num;
}

int smallest = numArray[0];

// Code to process array and look for smallest number
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++){
    if (numArray[i] < smallest){
        smallest = numArray[i];
    }
}

cout << endl << "The smallest number in the array is: " << smallest << endl << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++){
    int difference = numArray[i] - smallest;
    cout << "The difference between " << numArray[i] << " and the smallest number in the array is : " << difference << endl;
}

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: For future reference, this quote was confusing: "When you change the capacity, you don’t copy from the original array to the new one." Wasn't sure if that was an *instruction* of the assignment or simply an observation.

Comment: @ColinBasnett - I probably should have explained that that was a hint given by the person who was looking at my code. Whoops.

Answer (score 3):

In this bit of code

```
if (size == capacity){
    int *temp = new int[capacity + 2];
    capacity += 2;
    delete[]ptr;
    ptr = temp;
}
```

You create a new array but do not copy the existing arrays contents into it.

Add the following line just after creating the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < capacity ; ++i) temp[i] = ptr[i];
```

When coming to do the calculations you will have the entered values in the array.

Alternatively look into `std::vector`

Comment: Yes, but that seems to contradict the (somewhat odd) hint the OP was given.

Comment: @zdan - The comment can be read as a statement about the current behaviour

Comment: Unfortunately, I was restricted from using vectors. I implemented the line you suggested (and replaced all the numArray[i] 's with ptr[i] which I'm sure I'll find out was a mistake), and while it's reading all the numbers which are NOT -1 correctly, it is including -1 in the array, giving it a value of "-842150451", and just messing up the array size, and the equations

Comment: Change your `for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++){` to `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){` - This can be found using a debugger - a good tool to learn how to use